# Undefined variable in trait constructor

Tags: php, traits

I'm new to the idea of using traits. My understanding is that behavior can be shared in classes horizontally. In my project, the following code is repeatedly used at the top of every class.

```
class Loader {

    protected $options;

    /**
    * Loader constructor.
    */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->options = get_option( 'xenword_options' );
        $this->init();
    }
```

Since this is done in dozens of classes, would building a trait be a good direction to pursue?

This was my failed attempt. A file named Options.php was created. The contents are the following:

```
trait getOptions {
    public $options;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->$options = get_option('xenword_options');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, PhpStorm gives a message Undefined variable 'options.' This is not an issue when this code is in a class structure.

Since I'm new to traits, any advice and pointers would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

@SignpostMarv is right in the part that the `$this->$option` is wrong there, not because it is a syntax error, but because there is a typo with the `$`, should be `->options` not `->$options` (you can check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a40de64bb87d8838b5368dd6fe69d128603c37b).

And now that you have the trait you must include it in the classes

```
class Loader {
    use starter;
}

trait starter {
    protected $options;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->options = 'xenword_options';
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init() {
      $myClass = __CLASS__;
      echo "{$myClass} started";
    }
}
```

To test it just do `new Loader()` to see the message.
(check: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55b517142fb8d74b8b5a3e2246c79b6428330297)

Comment: Thank you! I absolutely missed the $.

Answer (score 0):

$this->$options is a syntax error.

you want $this->options.

Comment: _$this->$options is a syntax error._ this is not true (check: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a40de64bb87d8838b5368dd6fe69d128603c37b)

Comment: I'll phrase it another way; $options does not exist within scope, therefore it triggers an error. you want to use $this->options.